# count date per month , per year on database with date format with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

how to calculate the amount of data in 1bulan / 1 year on the basis of the date in the database based on the date format?i am using codeigniter

Example

> date    2016-02-10
>
> 2016-05-19
>
> 2016-07-20
>
> 2016-02-30
>
> 2016-05-20
>
> 2016-05-21

Result count

> data on Mounth Feb = 2
>
> data on Mounth May = 3
>
> data on Mounth Jul = 1

This My script

```
<?php 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbcounter ";
        $get_monthly = " WHERE date LIKE '".date("Y-m")."%'";
        $monthly = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql . $get_monthly));    
        echo $monthly;                      
?>
```

Comment: Please add more detail to the question as it is unclear

Comment: @noor, thanks noor i am update my question, i want if this month Feb how many visitor on Month Feb And other Months. retrieve data from a database with date format

Comment: Why you are not using active class ?

Comment: @Duwiirwanto Try my answer and let me know if that helps  :)

Comment: use `WHERE date = date( 'Y-m' )` .This will give you current month of current year data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DATE_FORMAT(`date_column`,'desired_output') as in this example:-
You can read about date function on http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
$date_variable = date("Y-m",strtotime('last month')); //prints 2016-01 
echo   $this->db->get_where("tbcounter",array("DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y-%m')"=> $date_variable ))->num_rows();
```

This is demo code :)

Comment: @Paveen Kumar nice..good... Can you give an example of the variable

Comment: @Paveen Kumar, Your answer is very helpful nice..workk , but how do I make a variable for the year and the month ? Can you give me an example

Comment: @Duwiirwanto You have to experiment with date function php... :) i gave a link to manuals. read and try hard.

Comment: thanks @Praveen Kumar it was very helpful to me and my problem is resolved , and I tried myself to experiment again date function

Answer (score 0):

For Counting data per year and per month you can use

```
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

In your query.

Example :

```
SELECT count( * )
FROM `TableNAme`
GROUP BY YEAR( `Date` )
LIMIT 0 , 30


SELECT count( * )
FROM `TableNAme`
GROUP BY MONTH( `Date` )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Here `Date` is your column name in table.

Comment: thanks @Bugfixer for answer but the results do not match the data in the database ?